# Understanding a theorem on the canonical form of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

> Theorem: Let $X$ be a manifold, $x \in X$ and let V be a vector field
> s.t. $V(x) \ne 0$. Then there exists a chart $(U,f)$ on $X$ such that
> $x \in U$ and for all $y \in U$, we have $\Delta_f (V(y)) =
>  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}|_{f(y)}$

My question is: what on earth does $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}|_{f(y)}$ mean?

The way I see it, $\Delta_f$ is a map from $T_y X$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}|_{f(y)}$ should be an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I don't know how to interpret this object. My first thought was that we're taking the partial derivative of $f(y)$ with respect to $x_1$ but this would always be $0$ since $f(y)$ is a constant vector so this doesn't make sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Please write $Df$ or $df$, not $\Delta_f$. That is completely non-standard notation. And $Df(y)$ maps $T_yX$ to $T_{f(y)}\Bbb R^n$, not to $\Bbb R^n$; admittedly, they are isomorphic vector spaces, but you need to keep things straight. You are ending up with the tangent vector $\partial/\partial x_1$ at the point $f(y)$. Using $x$ both for a point in $X$ and for coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$ is extremely confusing. Use a different letter for the standard coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the insight, I completely skipped over the fact that $Df(y)$ maps to $T_{f(y)} \mathbb{R}^n$. I find differential geometry difficult because there are so many similar notions (vector fields, tangent spaces, derivations) and somehow some of them turn out to be 'equivalent' objects, even though at first glance they seem totally different. 
As for the notation, this is the one that my Manifolds course uses and in particular the lecture notes from which the theorem was derived, so I have no choice but to use it for the time being. I did not realise it was non-standard.

Comment: Yeah, $\Delta$ is ordinarily used in geometry for the Laplace operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the statement is that you make the vector into $(1, 0, \ldots, 0),$ and this is what the formula really tells you.

The tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n,$ but really it is spanned by vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ (that is, it is a set of *derivations*), as for any manifold. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}|_{f(y)}$ is one of the basis vectors - as a derivation, what it does is it takes the $x_1$-derivative and *then* plugs in the points $f(y)$.

Comment: Thank you, this clears up my confusion :)